# Modify TFS Work Item Workflow to prevent state changes

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

We have a custom field on Bugs and User Stories of 'Traiged by', and the devs *shouldn't* start work on the ticket until it has been triaged by a product owner. What I'd like to do is prevent the state transition from New to Active when 'Triaged By' is null. Is this possible? I can't see any rules on the Workflow Transition dialog.

TFS 2017 Update 3 RTM/15.117.27024.0 on-premise. Agile process template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not able to do this.

You could not change a state based on filed valume/rules. You could also not able to skip/prevent transitions by specific field volume.

For System fields, there is some restriction for them. Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018#system-field-rules) for details:

> System fields have System.Name reference names, for example
>   System.Title and **System.State**. TFS restricts customization of
>   these fields, except for these instances:

Transitions define the valid progressions and regressions between states. **Users can specify only those states that are valid based on the transitions** that you define for the current state.

In the other word, Transitions tell the TFS which state can be followed by the current one.

A transition always has a from and to state. You could not **ignore** or skip the transition and select a totally different state. It's not available at present.

For more details of this related concept, you could take a look at our official tutorial here-- [Workflow design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-workflow-wit?view=azure-devops#workflow-design-guidelines)